# Set-Service fails when executing as part of a script but passes when running manually

Tags: powershell

As part of my script, I have the following code inside a powershell module.

```
Set-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $ComputerName -Status $ServiceStatus -Confirm:$false -Verbose;
```

When this runs in the script I get the following error

```
Set-Service : Service 'Service Name' cannot be configured due to the following error: The specified service does not exist as an installed service
```

But then when running manually as part of my testing the command runs without error.

```
Set-Service -Name "Service Name" -ComputerName "machine name" -Status Stopped -Confirm:$false -Verbose;
```

Comment: Does the specified service exist as an installed service?

Comment: Add some print statements to be sure that $ServiceName and $ComputerName really are strings and they really do hold the right values. Where do those strings come from? Would they happen to be properties on an object passing through a Select-Object filter? That often flummoxes people.